# In javascript, Is it possible to get all the relevant styles based on my current cursor position?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Let's say I've a markup like below

```
<div style="font-weight:bold;">Testing stting <i>sd <span style="color:red"> fdsf </span>ds</i></div>
```

a) If my cursor is in between the texts "fd" and "sf", it should return foreground color red,italic and bold 
b) similarly, if it is between texts "Test" and "ing", it should return bold alone.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you explain it more. Like how could the text would be italic and bold at the same time.

Comment: `$('*').click(function(){console.log($(this).css())})`